# Wordpress header.php file not reading function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mobile

In WordPress, a function in functions.php reads whether user is desktop or mobile machine.  Both header.php and page.php use function and insert variables $device and $style where needed.  Page.php uses this function properly.  However, header.php does not seem able to pull values from function.

This is the function:

```
function device_type($device,$style) {
global $device;
global $style;
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.     +firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',        $useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di| \-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|  do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|      hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|   kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|   02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2f]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|  p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|     s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|    mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|  voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{
$style = "style-mobile.css";
$device = "mobile";
} else {
$style = "style.css";
$device = "desktop";    
    }
}
```

This is header.php (the place the function is called is the last element in this code):

```
<?php
/**
* The Header template for our theme
*
* Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
* @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
*/
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<!-- SELECTING FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Covered+By+Your+Grace' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Puritan:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- SELECT DESKTOP/MOBILE STYLESHEET -->
<?php device_type($device,$style); ?>
<?php if($device == 'desktop'){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?><?php echo '/style-mobile.css" media="screen, handheld"' ?> />
<?php } ?>
</head>
```

This is the only code for the page.php:

```
<?php if($device == 'desktop'){ ?>
```

This is the site:

[http://rowlandwilliams.com/lepeep](http://rowlandwilliams.com/lepeep/)

Comment: Generally speaking, you're better off using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) rather than getting the user agent. With media queries, you can target screen sizes rather than specific devices.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the globals isn't really a good idea and is not the best solution since you can easily define them at the top of your file. I think the way wordpress handles the rendering of the page may be breaking your globals. I am not positive, and it doesn't matter because you shouldn't really do what you did...

This would be a better way to do what you did:

Functions:

```
function getDeviceType()
{
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.     +firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',        $useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di| \-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|  do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|      hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|   kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|   02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2f]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|  p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|     s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|    mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|  voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
    {
        return 'mobile';
    } else {
        return 'desktop';
    }
    return 'unknown';
}

function deviceTypeToStylesheet($deviceType)
{
    switch($deviceType)
    {
        case 'mobile':
            return 'style-mobile.css';
            break;
        case 'desktop':
            return 'style.css';
            break;
        default:
            return 'style.css';
            break;
    }
}
```

Truncated header file:

```
<?php
$deviceType = getDeviceType();
$deviceStylesheet = deviceTypeToStylesheet($deviceType);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- EXTRA CODE REMOVED FOR EXAMPLE -->

<!-- SELECT DESKTOP/MOBILE STYLESHEET -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/<?php echo $deviceStylesheet; ?>" media="screen, handheld" />

</head>
```

As for the preg match on your user agent, I just assumed you had it working the way you wanted. Given it actually looks up the right user agents, this should work and be a cleaner, easier to update, solution.

**UPDATE**
Page.php: The $device variable isn't magically known anymore because we are no longer using globals for this. You need to replace your global $devices with the function that returns the device name, getDeviceType(). You would do this EVERYWHERE you have used your old code involving the $device global.

```
<?php if(getDeviceType() === 'desktop'){ ?>
```

That should do the trick now :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, and that works with header.php, but it caused the page.php use of that function to stop working.

Comment: I didn't mean to submit that comment.

This is the code from the page.php file.  First, a modification of the code you provided:

    <?php
    $deviceType = getDeviceType();
    $device = deviceTypeToStylesheet($deviceType);
    ?>

And this is where the variable is tested:

    <?php if($device == 'desktop'){ ?>

When that test occurs, the page defaults to "else."  I even reversed the code you provided for the functions.php file, and still it defaulted to "else."  What am I not seeing?

Comment: I don't know because now there is a different file and code in question. Please update/fix your original question so we can see the appropriate code in question. Looking at code in comments gives me a headache as it's not formatted. After seeing the correct question, I will update my answer.

Comment: sorry I missed your first comment and understand. I still think the original question should be updated. It looks like page.php is still using your old code, as my new code does not use $device variable, so it would never be true... Replace ALL uses of your old code, and device checking, with my modified one.  Well, replace it on page.php and see if it fixes the problem, and do 1 file at a time, test.. Don't just blindly replace it on 100 files, just in case it needs edited.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about formatting. I tried inserting it and it wouldn't take.   I have added original page.php code. There isn't much there. And when I tried modifying code, I did one page at a time.  I learned that early on the hard way!   Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can only do inline code inside comments. The fully formatted code blocks is on questions/answers. I have updated my answer for page.php as well. You can not use $devices freely anymore. Use the function we made, getDeviceType(). - `if (getDeviceType() === 'desktop') {}` - And your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function before header, with add_action. Use a hook that occurs before header. This works for me.

```
function device_type ( $device, $style='' ) {
global $device;
global $style;

$i_am_mobile = true;

    if( $i_am_mobile ){
        $style = "style-mobile.css";
        $device = "mobile";
    } else {
        $style = "style.css";
        $device = "desktop";    
    }

}
add_action('init', 'device_type');
```

And on header.php

```
<?php 
global $style;
global $device;

// echo or do other things
echo $device;
echo $style; 
?>
```